# How do you plot an upside down histogram in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

Can you plot a histogram in matplotlib so that it appears upside down, i.e. the base of the histogram is along the top axis and it "hangs" down? Or, alternatively, if plotting with `orientation='horizontal'`, so that the base of the histogram is on the right hand axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `invert_yaxis`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,2,2],
             'b':[1,1,1,3,2,2,2]})
ax = df.plot.hist()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Output:

[image]